# How to receive notifications of packet delievery status

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, notifications, udp, wifi

I am now writing a program which should be able to dynamically select and switch 802.11 channels. Multiple threads can use a shared 802.11 radio. The goal is to let a thread lock the radio before switching channel, and then transmit one data packet, finally, unlock the radio after the data packet has been successfully transmitted out of the 802.11 NIC or dropped permanently.

But I can't find a way to know if a data packet has been transmitted out of the NIC card or it is still somewhere in the host. I am programming in C on Ubuntu. I use UDP socket to send the data packet. A successful return from "sendto" doesn't indicate that the data packet has been successful transmitted out of the hardware.

Could anyone point out a way to receive notifications of packet delivery status from 802.11? To sum up, I want to receive notifications when a data packet has been transmitted out of the NIC for broadcasting mode, and when a data packet has been successfully received by the other end or has been permanently dropped for unicast mode.

Any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not at all sure that either such notifications are possible.  The NIC L1 knows nothing about UDP datagrams.  It just shoves out bytes from buffers.  A buffer at L1 may, or may not, have a 1:1 correspondance with a UDP datagram at L2/3.  Similar problem with 'when a data packet has been successfully received by the other end' - such a notification would have to be sent back by either the peer L2/3, (and this is not done for UDP datagrams), or by the peer application.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your comments. I know if I enable 802.11 ARQ, every frame sent out will be acknowledged. But I don't know if the link layer ACKs can be accessed by upper layer protocols? Or if 802.11 MAC can notify upper layers about the delivery status of a specific data packet? Thank you again for your kind help.